# Two-level system with natural frequency $\omega_{21}$ exposed to an EM radiation of frequency $\omega$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics, two-level-system

Consider a two-level system with energies $E_1$ and $E_2(\gt E_1)$, and an energy gap $$E_2-E_1=\hbar\omega_{21}.$$ If this system is excited by an EM radiation of frequency $\omega(\lll\omega_{21})$, it has a negligible probability to excite the system by getting absorbed. In this case, what happens to the photon? Does it get scattered or simply transmitted? Please explain your answer.

Next, consider the other extreme case where the frequency of the exciting EM radiation $\omega\ggg\omega_{21}$. In this case, what is most likely to happen? Does the photon get scattered or transmitted?  Please explain why.

Comment: In case $\omega \ll \omega_{21}$,- it can't excite this system unless it's a non-linear multi-photon absorption process, i.e. $ 2 \omega =  \omega_{21}$ for example. But it has low probability, unless there's a huge stream of photons, i.e. very strong light source like laser. If you just push a lonely $\omega \ll \omega_{21}$ photon through the system,- according to quantum mechanics it will **not** excite it, system will be transparent to such photons.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Why transmitted? Why not reflected or scattered? And what about the other limit asked in the question?

Comment: I mean by transparent, that such photon will not be absorbed by this system, because this photon doesn't satisfy transition requirements.

Comment: But with absorption excluded, two other possibilities, namely, reflection/scattering and transmission/refraction are left open.